# Cannot connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH from Linux

Tags: ssh

I just got a fairly old model of Raspberry Pi (Model B with 512MB RAM). As I don't have an extra keyboard or screen, I'm trying to hook it up via ethernet with my laptop.

I copied a Raspbian image to a 16GB sd card. (2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch).
I also made an empty file named "ssh" under /boot

I enabled IPv4 to share the network via ethernet, and used nmap to check the IP of my Pi.
Result of the nmap is:

```
$nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-29 17:29 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.106
Host is up (0.00018s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.253
Host is up (0.12s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 10.13 seconds
```

According to ifconfig, my laptop's IP is 192.168.1.106, and I believe that 192.168.1.253 is the Raspberry.

I pinged 192.168.1.253, and it went through smoothly.

Then I tried to SSH into the Raspberry, but I always get "Connection timed out":

```
$ ssh -v pi@192.168.1.253
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.253 [192.168.1.253] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.253 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.253 port 22: Connection timed out
```

As for power issues, I have LEDs PWR (red), FDX (green), LNK (green) and 100 (orange) on. Does that mean that the power is OK? I only have an SD card, ethernet cable, and power connected to the Raspberry.

I don't get why can't I SSH to the Raspberry. It would be really nice if anyone can help.

My laptop is on Ubuntu 16.04.

I found that in my Raspberry, under /etc, there's no folder /etc/folder, nor is there the file "dhcpd.conf". Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: `nmap -sT -p22 192.168.1.0/24` should confirm whether the port is really open.  If so you should check the logs on the SD card; unfortunately the default logging configuration may complicate that -- you may need to apply `journald`, since it does not leave a plain text log, or you may get lucky and find one in `/var/log`.

Comment: What do you get for the result of `arp 192.168.1.253`?

Answer (score -1):

For security, on most RaspberryPi distributions the SSH service needs to be activated.  At [www.raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) are these instructions:

> ```
> Launch Raspberry Pi Configuration from the Preferences menu
> Navigate to the Interfaces tab
> Select Enabled next to SSH
> Click OK
> ```

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue—the OP says that they created `/boot/ssh`, which also works (see point 3 of the link you gave). It looks like it's something more complex instead.

Comment: I see what you are saying - @Aurora0001, perhaps you can explain.  This method of dropping a empty file named ssh in the /boot directory, is is permanent or does it just work for that one boot up?  I am asking as the instructions say the file is deleted after boot up.

Comment: I believe the setting is persistent; the file is just deleted so that if you later disable it, it won't immediately be re-enabled on next boot.